# In a Set Definition for 2 elements, what does $\Bbb N \times \Bbb N$ mean?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am asked how many elements are in the set:

$$\{(a,b) \mid a,b\in\Bbb N \times \Bbb N \;\;\text{and}\;\; 1\le a\le b \le 15\}$$

And I assumed it would be the triangle number of 15 until I saw the $\Bbb N \times \Bbb N$ within.

Can anyone explain to me what this means or is indicating, if anything, to the question?

Comment: I would write either $(a,b) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ or $a,b \in  \mathbb{N}$. I wouldn't write $a,b \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: What @T.Bongers said, basically. It's *supposed to be* a set of ordered pairs whose elements satisfy the inequalities shown. But "$a,b \in \Bbb N\times\Bbb N$" is actually not right; it should be either $a,b\in\Bbb N$ or $(a,b) \in \Bbb N\times\Bbb N$, not what's written.

Comment: Do you know what "ordered pair" is?

Comment: I figured that as it is ordered, it would actually be 120 orderings, $\frac{15 \times 16} 2$

Comment: @GarethAllen-Stringer Yep. $\sum_{1\le i\le 15} i$. 120 *ordered pairs*, not "orderings".

Comment: Just think about it this way if a=1 then there are 15 orderings, if a=2 there are 14 and so on. Hence there are 15+14+13=12+...+1=(15*16)/2=120 pairs as above.

Comment: @BrianO So, to clarify, would the correct answer be 120 elements despite the odd notation $a,b\in\Bbb N \times \Bbb N$?

Comment: Unless the problem is talking about elements like $((a,b),(x,y))$... but then using $\leq$ does not make sense.

Comment: @GarethAllen-Stringer Yes I'm sure that's the desired result. If possible, you might mention in your answer that the problem contains a typo. (if $a,b\in \Bbb N\times \Bbb N$ then each of $a,b$ itself an ordered pair, and you can't compare those with $1$ or $15$ -- clearly they're supposed to be integers. Missing parentheses around "$a,b$".)

Comment: @BrianO Cheers, I'll make sure to mention it.

Comment: Last word: the set can be written as $\{(a,b)\in\Bbb N\times\Bbb N\mid 1\le a\le b\le 15\}$.

Comment: @BrianO I believe the reason it's defined with the vertical bar is because within the same module we are learning Haskell, and Haskell uses List Comprehensions of the same format. Probably the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general,$$\mathbb{A}\times \mathbb{B} = \{(x,y)| x\in\mathbb{A}, y \in \mathbb{B}\}$$

One approach to the answer would be to fix $a = 1$ and run through $15$ possibilities of $b$. Then fix $a = 2$ and run through $14$ possibilities of $b$ (there are now $14$ since $a\leq b$). Continuing like this we see there are a total of

$$1+2+3+...+15 = \frac{15\cdot16}{2} = 120$$
such ordered pairs.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, the $a,b\in\Bbb N \times \Bbb N$ really threw me. Somebody commented about it involving the cartesian product, but its involvement in this problem doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: No problem :) the most likely explanation for the unusual notation is a typo in the question.

Answer (score 0):

$A \times B$ is the Cartesian product of $A$ and $B$, defined by $$A \times B = \{(a,b) : a \in A \text{ and } b \in B\}.$$

The notation $a,b \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ strikes me as strange. I would have written the set in question as $$\{(a,b) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} : 1 \le a \le b \le 15 \}.$$

Comment: There are not 15 elements in the set. There are, in fact, 15 elements $(a,b)$ in the set with $b = 15$, and then more with $b\ne 15$.

Comment: There are already 15 elements if you fix $a = 1$

Comment: So when $a = 1, n(b) = 15$ and when $a = 2, n(b) = 14$ etc. all the way to $a = 15, b = 15$, no? Hence why I think it's the triangle number of 15, 120.

Comment: My apologies, BrianO and Daniel. The last line was typed hastily. I have removed the error from my answer. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: @GarethAllen-Stringer, you were correct. Please excuse the error in my previous answer. The 15th _triangular number_, not the _number_ 15, is the number of elements in the set. Best regards.